Not able to run specific tf file
I want to run specific terraform file but it is running different tf file . My directory structure is given below
[root@localhost Basics]# pwd
/root/terraform_practicals/Basics
[root@localhost Basics]# ll
total 20
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   74 Oct 13 15:21 file_destructure
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   68 Oct 13 15:21 Functions
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   97 Jul  7 16:33 Hello.tf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   94 Jul  7 16:56 Hello.tf.json.disabled
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1871 Aug 20 09:29 main.tfplan
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  168 Jul  7 17:45 multiple_blocks.tf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  180 Dec 15 12:44 terraform.tfstate
drwxr-xr-x. 8 root root  171 Oct 13 15:21 variable

[root@localhost terraform_practicals]#

When i run terraform plan list.tf , it is giving below error
[root@localhost Basics]# terraform plan Hello.tf
╷
│ Error: Too many command line arguments
│
│ To specify a working directory for the plan, use the global -chdir flag.
╵

For more help on using this command, run:
  terraform plan -help

And while running terraform plan it will run different tf file
[root@localhost Basics]# terraform plan

Changes to Outputs:
  + Country   = "India"
  + FirstName = "Aniket"
  + Hello     = "Hello Terraform"
  + LastName  = "Pant"

You can apply this plan to save these new output values to the Terraform state, without changing any real infrastructure.

─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Note: You didn't use the -out option to save this plan, so Terraform can't guarantee to take exactly these actions if you run
"terraform apply" now.


Terraform version=1.10.2

Although this is a duplicate question, I want to say that you wrote the question very well -- you included an appropriate level of detail, and clearly described both what you were seeing and what you were trying to achieve. It was easy to skim read your question and understand what you were asking.
